# Amazon AWS PHP SDK 2 PharException thrown with suhosin installed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phar

Using the PHP SDK 2 provided by Amazon AWS and released as a phar archive I get the following error on a QA server (dev is fine)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 
    '__HALT_COMPILER(); must be declared in a phar' in /home/www/libs/s3/aws.phar:17 
    Stack trace: #0 /home/www/libs/s3/aws.phar(17): Phar::mapPhar('aws.phar') 
                        #1 /home/www/libs/...
                        ...
```

Searching around I find that this is probably related to the suhosin security extension.  I need to keep the eaccelerator running, and would like to keep the hardened server. Details from phpinfo() are

```
PHP Version 5.3.19-1~dotdeb.0

This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.10
Copyright (c) 2006-2007 Hardened-PHP Project Copyright (c) 2007-2012 SektionEins GmbH

eAccelerator

eAccelerator support    enabled
Version         0.9.6.1
Caching Enabled     true
Optimizer Enabled       true
Check mtime Enabled     true
...
```

php.ini does have suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"

Has anyone else experienced this?

(I have posted a similar question on the AWS PHP support forum)

Any ideas on how to get the aws.phar working with suhosin installed?

Comment: Well, the error is totally right: `__HALT_COMPILER()` *must* be declared in a phar as part of the stub.  This is a bug in the AWS library.

Comment: @Charles - I agree -- it also seems suhosin is no longer under active maintenance and even dropped from debian php5 recommended packages. I've updated QA & and live to php5.4 without suhosin, the exceptions no longer appear. Won't be an option for anyone on shared hosting!